# Can't close the colorbox window from the iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, colorbox

i am attaching this event to a link (inside the iframe)

```
window.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

but it fires on firebug:

```
Permission denied to access property '$'
[Parar en este error]   

window.parent.$.fn.colorbox.close();
```

And the window won't close,

any idea? in the iframe file i am importing colorbox.js and jquery.js

And also tried

```
$(this).parents('iframe').hide()
```

but with no result...

Comment: does the iframe belong to your domain?

Comment: What JIA said + have you tried switching $ to `jQuery` ?

Comment: yes it does; it has a relative path. I tried &@jQuery with no success... :(

Comment: have you tried to declare function in `window.parent`, and call it from `iframe`? E.g. `function closeColorBox() { $.fn.colorbox.close(); }` and call `window.parent.closeColorBox();`?

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue. Is the iframe on a different domain? Mine was, so the child scripts were being prevented from communicating with the parent window.

Ben Alaman's jQuery postMessage plugin was the only thing that finally worked for me: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-postmessage-plugin/
I did the following:

```
parent.$.postMessage('$(".myID").colorbox.close();', parent_url, parent.parent);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $('#cboxClose').remove(); to close the colorbox from inside the iframe.